# Integration of Google+ API in Java

Tags: api, google-plus, integration

I have been searching for Google+ API integration with Java. All I got is that there is read-only access to it using Google+ Domain API. Is there any possible way, we can integrate google plus API in Java other than using domain API?

Comment: Integrate it how and to do what?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, Google Plus api are restricted to read only mode and you can access them only by domain api.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15655662)

Comment: This question doesn't have any solution right now. Thanks for your feedback. :)